# Wrap a quote in differently styled quotes depending on locale?

Tags: templating

I want to show quotes for my french visitors like so:

> « Something intelligent someone said. »

but visitors of my english locale should see the quotes formatted like so:

> “Something intelligent someone said.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by adding the locale ID as a class to the body tag and then use a technique like described in this nice CSS-Tricks to add the quotes depending on that body class.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/q/quotes/

If you want them to be in the HTML you could write a quick Twig macro that adds the quotes depending on the locale ID.

```
{% macro wrapInQuotes(string) %}
    {%- set quotes = {
        'en': ['“', '”'],
        'de': ['„', '“'],
        'fr': ['« ', ' »'],
    } %}

    {{- quotes[craft.locale][0] }}
    {{- string }}
    {{- quotes[craft.locale][1] -}}
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as macros %}
{{ macros.wrapInQuotes(entry.quote) }}
```